# Ошибка запуска Perl скрипта из под Windows

Tags: windows, perl

Возникла необходимость переформатировать файл описания графов .GDL в формат .DOT.
На просторах интернета нашел скрипт под PERL, но как это не печально он брыкается, т.к. в нем вставлена команда OC Linux CAT.
У Windows соответственно такой команды конкатенации нет.
Какая конструкция может заменить эту команду.
Вот этот фрагмент.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict; 

my $FILE1 = $ARGV[0]; 
open(OUTFILE, ">".$FILE1.".dot") or die "File doesn't exist\n"; 
my $indata = `cat $FILE1`;
```

Этот скрипт я взял [тут](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=IDA_Pro).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```
my $indata = do { local $/; open(my $fl, "<", $FILE1); <$fl> };
```

Проверок на ошибки при открытии файла нет, т. к. при запуске `cat` так же будет получена пустая переменная при его отсутствии.